How to convert byte array to string and back?
I'm converting byte[] to string and back.
The byte[] converted back is not identical to the original.
How do I convert bytes to string and back correctly?
A console application to illustrate this:
Program.cs
_ = new TestByteConversion();

TestByteConversion.cs
internal class TestByteConversion
{
    public TestByteConversion()
    {
        var aes = Aes.Create();
        aes.GenerateKey();
        var keyAsString = GetKeyAsString(aes.Key);

        // I save it in a key value pair as string.
        // I get the value as string from dictionary.
        var keyAsyBytes = GetKeyFromString(keyAsString);

        // USE NuGet ConsoleTables !
        var table = new ConsoleTable("ID", "origin", "char", "new value");

        for (var i = 0; i < keyAsString.Length; i++)
        {
            table.AddRow(i, aes.Key[i], keyAsString[i], keyAsyBytes[i]);
        }

        table.Write();
    }

    public static byte[] GetKeyFromString(string keyAsString)
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyAsString);
    }

    public static string GetKeyAsString(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(byteArray);
    }
}


Encoding.ASCII.GetString does not do what you think it does...

I suggest you first learn about Base16, Base64, etc.

If you want a printable/readable representation of the key: use Convert.ToBase64String instead

You may also be interested in Converting a string to byte-array without using an encoding (byte-by-byte)

Also what does AES have to do with this?

There are many algorithms - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding

From the ASCIIEncoding.GetString docs:

ASCIIEncoding does not provide error detection. Any byte greater than hexadecimal 0x7F is decoded as the Unicode question mark ("?").

And 0x7F is 127, while byte is up to 255, so if the key has any element greater than 0x7F you will end up with non-reversible transformation.
You can use Convert.ToBase64String/Convert.FromBase64String methods instead (or Convert.ToHexString/Convert.FromHexString). For example:
var array = Enumerable.Range(0, 256)
    .Select(i => (byte)i)
    .ToArray();
var s = Convert.ToHexString(array);
var bytes = Convert.FromHexString(s);
var sequenceEqual = bytes.SequenceEqual(array);
Console.WriteLine(sequenceEqual); prints "True"


UTF-8 won't convert cleanly either, as there are sequences of bytes that are invalid UTF-8.  If your bytes are strictly bytes and not a previously encoded string, only the base64 stuff is likely to work.

@cHao yes, thank you! was in process of testing it =)
